# Haskell platfrom 2010 2.0.0 installtion error writing to file libHSGHC 6.12.3.p.a

Tags: haskell, ghc

Hi i have extract error
Output folder: C:\Haskell Platform\2010.2.0.0\Extract: libHSghc-6.12.3_p.a... 63%

error  writing to file libHSGHC 6.12.3.p.a
My machine win xp sp3 i have Disk D:\ with windows And also have Disk c:\ I trying istall it to C:\Program Files/Hasekl Platform 2010 2.0
I also have WinHugs,GtkSharp, VS200,Avast(it was disabbled)
I also tried Haskell Platform 2010 01.00same error.
I installing at admin accaunt. Folder program files also have full access to System and admin user.
EDIT
PROBLEM was in Disk space.
Now problem solved. Thanks for the fast answer :-)

Comment: The obvious first query is - do you have enough disk space? The HP on Windows is something over 700MB.

Comment: thank you. Problem with disk space solved and all works fine

Comment: @stephen Why not write that as the answer so that he can mark it as such and people stop looking here? And you'll get some rep too.

Comment: I see label you can accept your own answer wait two days. Write your answer as post and  will mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

Problem was in Disk space. I just incease emty space on both disks

Comment: And that's because of a retarded way that compiler was made. It writes some 1 Gb of data into your temp directory on your system drive. And I have no idea, why.